# Getting current guild id for instance

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm making a discord bot, and I want it to be able to obtain the guild ID of the guild where a command was issued. How would I go about implementing this? I tried using bot.guilds, but I need a method of nailing down the exact id.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a lot of information. Please look at ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question. Add every information you have that might help us, but keep it as short as possible. If you have a question about code, please include the code. You can also take this short [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does `ctx.guild.id` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing `message.guild.id` ?

That should return the guild id for the guild the command was executed in.